# Invalid configuration of route 'login': one of the following must be provided (component or redirectTo or children or loadChildren)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am learning Angular 2,I encounter this issue using RC7.

**app.routing.ts :**

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginRoutes } from './login/index';
import { DashboardRoutes } from './dashboard/index';

const routes: Routes = [
     ...LoginRoutes,
    ...DashboardRoutes
   //{ path:'', component: GridViewComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: []
})

export class Ng2PlayRoutingModule { }
```

**login.routes.ts**

```
import { LoginComponent } from './index';

export const LoginRoutes = [
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {   path: '', 
        redirectTo: 'dashboard/gridview', 
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
```

**dashboard.routes.ts**

```
 import { DashboardComponent } from './index';
    import { GridRoutes } from './gridview/index';

    export const DashboardRoutes = [
        {
            path: 'dashboard',
            component: DashboardComponent,
            children: [
                ...GridRoutes
            ]
        }
    ];
```

Here, when page loads it is redirects to **dashboard/gridview**. And it is not showing up anything and getting this error in console

```
zone.js:388Unhandled Promise rejection: Invalid configuration of route 'login': one of the following must be provided (component or redirectTo or children or loadChildren) ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ;
```

Help me what is causing issue.

**Edit:**

**login/index.ts**

```
export * from './login.component';
export * from './login.routes';
```

Comment: what are the configuration for DashboardRoutes ?

Comment: @ranakrunal9, see my edit.

Comment: your error is for `login` route in which you have set `component` equal to `LoginComponent` so i think its not importing `LoginComponent` or not identifying `LoginComponent` inside your `login.routes.ts`

Comment: see my edit, I have included both component and router inside **index.ts**

Comment: change `import { LoginComponent } from './index';` to `import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';` and check it

Comment: Cannot find module './login.component'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127347/discussion-between-nnr-and-ranakrunal9).